# Is it possible to define a function with properties in TypeScript without a type assertion or intermediate?

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects

TypeScript lets you define an interface which is both callable and has properties:

```
interface FnWithProps {
    (x: number): number;
    a: string;
    b: string;
}
```

Here's one way to create values assignable to this interface:

```
function double(x: number) {
    return x * x;
}
double.a = 'Hello';
double.b = 'Goodbye';

let f: FnWithProps = double;  // ok
```

If `double.a` or `double.b` are not set, this triggers an error.

Is it possible to construct such a value directly, without going through an intermediate or using a type assertion?

This isn't valid TypeScript and triggers all sorts of errors:

```
let g: FnWithProps = {
    (x: number) => x,
    a: 'Hello',
    b: 'Goodbye',
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the intermediate solution is probably the best one as it works well for overloads too, but you can also use `Object.assign` to get a similar effect :

```
let f: FnWithProps = Object.assign(function double(x: number) {
    return x * x;
},{
    a : 'Hello',
    b : 'Goodbye'
});
```

Although this does mean we don't get inference for the function params or the properties.

If this is a common scenario for you, we can build a utility function to get inference for everything:

```
interface FnWithProps {
    (x: number): number;
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

function functionWithProps<T extends (...a: any[]) => any>(fn: (...a: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>, props: Pick<T, keyof T>){
    return Object.assign(fn, props);
}

let f = functionWithProps<FnWithProps>(function double(x) { // annotation not necesary
    return x * x;
},{
    a : 'Hello', // helpful intelisense here
    b : 'Goodbye'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Using `interface FnWithProps` from original post

```js
interface FnWithProps {
    (x: number): number;
    a: number;
    b: number;
}
const g:FnWithProps = (()=>{
    const obj={
        a:2,b:3,
        func:function(x:number){ return this.a*x+this.b}
    }
    return obj.func.bind({a:obj.a,b:obj.b}) as FnWithProps
})()
console.log(g(1))
```

[Demo in typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIgOrDACwApQD2ADgM7IDeAUMrcgBQAeAXMiAK4C2ARtAJSsOPaAG4adOIK68oYusm5ThsqgF8qVBIRCkwyAObN0WXARLkAvA3p8LAPmrytOvYW4ArC4-kTmAJgAaRQBmAPEfZBh2EARmKJiwYG0mZiEZPgpkKAgwdigQZFxgUgA6OAAqRgBqItLudXkGumzc-OQ3dxL4hBLuUAATegpJDrKg5lH6vmQ4cmNsfCIyNT4bDWdSQgAbCBKtwn16Q4BGPj4NIA)

The thing to note here is that `this` for the definition of the function is `obj`.  That's required to prevent errors with reference to this.  However, after it is taken out of `obj`, this `this` is lost!  So it is replaced by using bind.  (Assign would have worked as well).

As an aside, an alternative to using `interface` is as follows:

```js
type Fn = (x:number)=>number
type Props = { a: string, b:string}
const g=(function():Fn & Props{
  const f=(x:number)=>x*x
  f.a='Hello'
  f.b='Goodbye'
  return f  // type checking properly applied here
})()
```